# How do I redirect site request to www. while on HTTPS?

Tags: nginx, https

I am not able to redirect the https://example.org to https://www.example.org , here is how my configurations looks like:

```
server {
        listen 443;
        server_name www.example.org;
       #
       #more configuration here;
       #
}
server {
        listen 443;
        server_name example.org;
        return 301 https://www.example.org$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: I don't see `ssl` flag on `listen`. Also, what exactly do not work? No redirect? No connect? Bad certificate?

Comment: redirect was not working. you are right ssl flag was not there. It's fixed now. Thanks for the insight :)

Answer (score 0):

```
       return 301 https://www.example$request_uri;
                                    ^^^^
```

Missing a `.org`, perhaps?

Comment: typo there, I have edited the question, please check it now.

Answer (score 0):

So this configuration worked for me, I had missed the **ssl flag** on the configuration. thanks  [Alexey Ten](https://serverfault.com/users/211028/alexey-ten) for the insight.

```
## Main configuration
server {
        listen 443;
        ssl on;
        server_name www.example.org;
        ssl_certificate /home/user/example.org/example.org.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/user/example.org/example.org.key;
       #
       #more configuration here;
       #
}

## Redirect
server {
        listen 443;
        server_name example.org;
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /home/user/example.org/example.org.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/user/example.org/example.org.key;

        return 301 https://www.example.org$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: You have duplicate `return` directive.

Comment: Use `listen 443 ssl;` and remove `ssl on;` as it's deprecated for a long time already